# Invalid Object Name with TPC Hierarchy

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this simple model:

```
public Store
{
    public virtual Id { get; protected set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UserBase> Users { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract UserBase
{
    public virtual Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string EMail { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}

public Customer : UserBase
{
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this Fluent Mapping:

```
public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
{
    public StoreMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        HasMany(x => x.Users).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class UserBaseMap : ClassMap<UserBase>
{
    public UserBaseMap()
    {
        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.EMail).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Password).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class CustomerMap : SubclassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap ()
    {
        Abstract();

        Map(x => x.Address).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

This is a mapping for a Table Per Concrete mapping, and the database schema is generated as expected (No UserBase table, which is good).

But when I try to add the customer to the Users Collection:

```
using (var t = session.BeginTransaction()) {
    var myCustomer = new Customer { EMail = "mail@mail.com", Password = "YouShouldntLookAtThis" };
    var store = GenericRepository.GetById<Store>(RootId);
    store.Users.Add(myCustomer);
    t.Commit();
}
```

I got the following Exception:

> Detalles de la excepción: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'UserBase'.

I think is a mapping issue, but I can't see the problem. Can you help me figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 5 cents

Can you change the mapping of Customer class to include tablename

Table("Customer");

Comment: Did you checked the schema ? like adding this line in the mapping : Schema("dbo");

Comment: Yes, the schema is allright. I generate the database, the retrieves work great. I only have this problem when I try to add a Customer to a collection of UserBase

Comment: One more option is  use Abstract(); in the UserBaseClass Mapping. That is if the base class is not abstract then an additional table ( USERBASE in the example above) is needed to hold instances of the superclass.